# gradle.xml not consistent between platforms

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I develop using Android Studio on both Macs and PCs, and am seeing undesired behavior when moving projects between the two platforms.

One of those issues is regarding the "gradleHome" value in **'.idea/gradle.xml'**, which is a correct-looking value **on the Mac**:

```
<option name="gradleHome" value="$APPLICATION_HOME_DIR$/gradle/gradle-2.10" />
```

When I check out the project and load it into Android Studio on Windows, the **'.idea/gradle.xml'** value for "gradleHome" becomes a hard-coded path:

```
<option name="gradleHome" value="C:\Program Files\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.10" />
```

Obviously problems will ensue if the file is checked in with a hard-coded path, but there seems nothing I can do but ignore this change during checkin.

Does anyone know why this is happening or how to prevent it? Should I not be checking this file into SVN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This file should not be checked into version-control. What can go into version-control and defines the gradle-version is this file: gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties - I would ignore the whole .idea directory. 
On a side node - think about using git over svn - if you really need svn as a storage there is git-svn ..

Comment: Thanks! The whole subject of what should and shouldn't get checked in from Android Studio projects is very confusing. Everywhere I look there are different opinions.  Is it best practice to ignore the entire .idea directory?

Comment: yes - the build is defined in the gradle-files - afair IDEA files are also in the default gitignore that is created alongside a new project

Comment: ".idea/gradle.xml" is not contained within my ".gitignore" file:

*.iml
.gradle
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
/.idea/libraries
.DS_Store
/build
/captures

Comment: Note also that the above comment is the perfect example of why Stack Overflow comments should allow newlines.